# Redirect to index Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2

I'm having problem with redirecting.
How do i redirect localhost/volleyball to localhost/volleyball/index.php?
because it displays my directory i want it to point to index.php. Btw, i'm using Codeigniter2.2

here's my .htaccess:

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /volleyball/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

i got the answer, i added:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: it work as i wanted it to be. maybe my question is confusing my apology. thank you for the info.